# Random seed in a bash script

Tags: bash, random-seed

I want to create a random seed in a bash script but somehow know how to calculate the same random seed again later on.
Suppose I have a range of servers id : 1 to 10. I want to randomly select a server to run a test on. I can do that by using the RANDOM function and see the value

```
echo $((1 + RANDOM % 10))
6
```

Then run the test on server id 6.

I do this in a loop for 5 times.

Is there a way to re-calculate the values (ids of servers) later on to see where the tests were ran on ? I should mention I do not wish to store the ids in an array.

Or if there is a way other than using the RANDOM function to accomplish this ?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want re-playable "random" sequence, you could use the command `shuf`:

```
$ printf '%s\n' server{1..10} | shuf --random-source file
server3
server6
server5
server9
server1
server2
server4
server8
server7
server10
```

As long as you use the same `file` as random source, the sequence will stay the same and could be replayed in the same order.

For info, you can also use the command `shuf -e server{1..10} --random-source file` if you want to get rid of the `printf ... |` command.

Use `-i` option of this `shuf` command and if you have a consecutive range of number to shuffle.

Comment: Nice info about `--random-source`. Use `printf '%s\n' server{1..10}` to avoid an unnecessary shell loop.

Comment: @TomFenech Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @TomFenech FYI By re-reading the man, I see that  `shuf -e` option can get rid of `printf`...